# Header and footer automatically in each page of the document

Tags: graphics

I would like to have a specific header and footer that are included automatically into my document. I have the following MWE (taken from another thread here):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
      \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}
    }
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[height=2.6cm, width=0.7\paperwidth]{example-image-b}}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The problem I have is that the image in the header has the size I need (anyway I can change it), but I cannot center it. Any suggestion about it? Thanks

Comment: use `\makebox[\paperwidth]` there too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did but the image in the header disappears.

Comment: It works: `\AtPageUpperLeft{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}}}`.

Comment: @frougon. You are right it works. My mistake in organizing the line

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Thanks it worked.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `\makebox` in the header too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
      \makebox[\paperwidth]{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\paperwidth]{example-image-a}}}%
    }
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[height=2.6cm, width=0.7\paperwidth]{example-image-b}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]